# No sound over pulseaudio in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I today rebooted computer and suddenly had no sound over pulse audio.
When I test sound in Sound Settings it works perfectly.
But when I run totem, rhythmbox, flash or anything else there is no sound.  Alsa works just fine.

Comment: Yesterday, I played a video with sound over HDMI. Maybe something changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into sound settings if specific applications aren't muted.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what to look for?

Comment: Click on the sound indicator, choose sound settings, then applications. Look into the settings if somewhere isn't sound muted.